Android 9 - Request Failed on production apk - http failure response (Unknown Error)
I'm always getting this error when try to open app in production apk on a device using Android 9.

The app on development environment (not signed apk) was working well with Android 9.
Anything else I'm missing that might caused this error?

Did you add networkSecurityConfig?

Yes. I have added.

Add android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" to the <application tag in app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.
With a corresponding network_security_config.xml in app/src/main/res/xml/:





Can you check if you're getting any exceptions in the log? If yes please add it to the question. Also check what is the API response.

is your domain  https  or http  ?



I am not getting any api log from the application. The application cannot call the api after signing the production environment apk. The local test environment is still logged and active.


My domain uses https.


I think my application has been blocked by Google Play, before that users could still download and use on Android 9. But I did not receive any notification and also did not understand what Google Play policy the application violated


